# Word Frequency without stopwords using egrep

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, grep, frequency

I want to count the word-frequency in a literary text "text.txt" without counting stopwords (from a list called "stopwords.txt") using the terminal.

```
cat text.txt | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | egrep -vwFf stopwords.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Why does this don't work and what should be the correct script like?

Note: the output should be sorted from low frequenzy to high!

Comment: post sample input output files

Comment: On my computer, your `egrep -vwFf` returns the error : `grep: conflicting matchers specified`. Simply removing the `F`flag fixes this for me.

Comment: @Aserre that is a good point

Comment: When you like pipes, append `| sort -n` for sorting on frequency.

Comment: @WalterA it gives me the frequezy list, but within the stopwords

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `awk` to do this with one process rather than a less efficient pipe:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[^[:alpha:]]"} 
     /^$/{next}
     {word=tolower($1)}
     FNR==NR {stop[word]; next}
     word in stop {next}
     {wc[word]++}
     END{ for (e in wc) printf "%4d\t%s\n", wc[e], e }
     ' stopwords words
```

(`gawk` only in this case...)

POSIX awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[^[:alpha:]]"} 
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
         word=tolower($i)
         if (FNR==NR)
             stop[word]
         else if (word in stop || $i~/^$/)
             continue
         else   
             wc[word]++   
        }
     }   
     END{ for (e in wc) printf "%4d\t%s\n", wc[e], e }
     ' stopwords words
```

Then your 'pipe' can be to call `sort` on that with `| sort -n`

Comment: thanks! that would be a noce solution; but I want to do it with pipes …